# How to migrate data to same structure table via MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql

I need to create insert trigger form old_table to new_table. both of table are same structure but I have to move because old_table has no partition and unique key. Who one can help me to writing insert?.

Comment: Why not simply copy the data from old table to new table, and assigning the unique keys?

Comment: Data is over 100GB. Moving is using long time. When new data coming i need to auto insert to other table